# jQuery note in Section 5.2.2 of W3C DOM4 Specification

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, w3c

Is there anyone that can explain the note on [section 5.2.2 of the W3C DOM4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-nonelementparentnode)?

Relevant Quote:

> **Note:** The `getElementById()` method is not on elements for compatibility with older versions of jQuery. If a time comes where that version of jQuery has disappeared, we might be able to support it.

I'm curious how this interface would explicitly cause a problem with `jQuery` and what versions, does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Nan answer, it probably has something to do with jQuery using `getElementById` to validate a step in an iteration. Adding this method to `HTMLElement` would make some conditions validate when part of jQuery code depends on it not validating.

Hard to say exactly which version causes the problem and in exactly which situations, but a quick look to old jQuery versions, you can see that `find()` in older version isn't compatible with Elements having `getElementById` method.

Going back to version 1.3, you can try to add the method to HTMLElement and you'll see that it messes the result. More recent version handle this correctly. See snippet:

```js
alert('Without getElementById method on HTMLElement, length of $("div").find("#test") is ' + $('div').find('#test').length);
window.HTMLElement.prototype.getElementById = function(str){
    console.log(str);
    return str;
}

alert('With getElementById method on HTMLElement, length of $("div").find("#test") is ' + $('div').find('#test').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.js"></script>
<div id="container"><div id="test"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `getElementById` method is only present on `document` global object, and it's not part of the DOM4 `Element` object *yet*.

This is due to compatibility issues with an older version of jQuery as you can read on DOM4 specification.

But, what does all this means? it means that W3C tried to add this method into the `Element` object and also means that once this "version of jQuery" disapear we "might" be able to chain `getElementById()` calls like this:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("header").getElementById("slogan");
```

Nothing special, they didn't want the most popular DOM manipulation wrapper to crash or jQuery as a [member of the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Member/List#xJ) has had some influence over this decision